# Gorm multiple transactions to remove old search conditions

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
    bg := Db.Begin()
    UDebt := make([]UserDebt, 0)
    page, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.DefaultPostForm("page", "1"))
    limit, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.DefaultPostForm("limit", "20"))
    db := Db.Model(&UDebt).Preload("User")
    start := c.PostForm("start")
    if start != "" {
        db = db.Where("datetime >= ?", start)
        bg = bg.Where("datetime >= ?", start)
    }

    debts := make([]UserDebt,0)
    bg.Debug().Set("gorm:query_option", "FOR UPDATE").Limit(limit).Offset(page).Find(&debts)
    // show sql: SELECT * FROM `user_debt`  WHERE (datetime >= '2019-06-16 00:00:00') LIMIT 20 OFFSET 1 FOR UPDATE
    // I hope this is a new connection without any conditions.
    bg.Debug().Model(&UserBet{}).Where("id in (?)",arrayID).Update("is_read",1)
    // show sql: UPDATE `user_bet` SET `is_read` = '1'  WHERE (datetime >= '2019-06-16 00:00:00') AND (id in ('17','18','19','20','21','22'))  
    bg.Commit()
```

I want the second SQL to remove the datetime condition.
The second SQL takes the first SQL search condition. How do I remove this condition and use it in a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having two separate query objects:

```
    bg := Db.Begin()
    UDebt := make([]UserDebt, 0)
    page, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.DefaultPostForm("page", "1"))
    limit, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.DefaultPostForm("limit", "20"))
    // Use the bg object so this is all done in the transaction
    db := bg.Model(&UDebt).Preload("User")
    start := c.PostForm("start")
    if start != "" {
        // Don't change the original bg object
        db = db.Where("datetime >= ?", start)
    }

    debts := make([]UserDebt,0)
    // Use the newly created db object to store the query options for that
    db.Debug().Set("gorm:query_option", "FOR UPDATE").Limit(limit).Offset(page).Find(&debts)
    bg.Debug().Model(&UserBet{}).Where("id in (?)",arrayID).Update("is_read",1)
    bg.Commit()
```

Comment: I want the first SQL to have a datetime condition, and the second SQL without a datetime condition.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the above code is doing.  Most gorm methods return a query object, so in order to have two different where clauses you'll need two different objects, as in the code above.  For the query without a datetime condition, I just use the original transaction object, as it comes without any conditions by default.  For the query with a datetime, we create a new object.